# C# LINQ get unique datarows from dataset only two columns

Tags: c#, linq, field, unique, rows

I am loading data from database and fill dataset with detailed records with studentId column duplicated in many records. Also using the following code to get distinct data rows from dataset:

```
tbl=tbl.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("studentId"))
.Select(group =>group.First())
.CopyToDataTable();
```

This returns all the columns in the unique data rows.
My question, how to select only particular columns? say studentId, studentName, birthdate?

Comment: You could try `.Select(group => new { group.First().studentId, group.First().studentName, group.First().birthdate})`

Comment: You cannot copy a single column from a data and then use CopyToDataTable().  The output table and input table has to have the same schema.  So you can have group.First()[column name or index].

Answer (score 0):

```
tbl=tbl.AsEnumerable()
  .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("studentId"))
  .Select(group =>group.First())

  .Select(s=> new {
    s.studentId,
    s.studentName,
    s.birthdate
  })
  .CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: would you type the full statement please

Comment: studentId, studentName and birthdate are unknown

Comment: I have no idea what your data structure is, that part you need to work out.  What I've given you is the concept.  What options do you get in your intellisense popup... when you type s.?

Comment: You have ItemArray and Field and other options

Comment: The point is I have nothing to work with here only your verse terse snippet.  My select statement is the way to do what you want but you need to work out how to get the columns from the underlying source which get projected using the final select

Comment: By the way rather than use AsEnumerable() try ToList()

Comment: I am stuck with that part where to specify the column!

Comment: Mate, with that exclamation I'm tempted to just walk away and leave you stuck...but I'll try one last time but you're going to need to help out by providing a full example.  From my end I have NO idea what the type of tbl is.  Can you please provide information on how to setup this project locally, or even make the solution available for download?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149348/discussion-between-hilal-al-rajhi-and-stephen-york).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use select like this:

```
  tbl = tbl.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("studentId"))
                .Select(group => new {
                    studentId = group.FirstOrDefault().studentId,
                    studentName = group.FirstOrDefault().studentName,
                    birthdate = group.FirstOrDefault().birthdate
                })
                .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: If `FirstOrDefault()` is called when there are no elements, it will return null, and your code will throw a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I do not think so it will return no results.

Comment: Ah, indeed you're right, I failed to see that GroupBy will never return empty set, since it wouldn't group those in the first place. I only looked at the `FirstOrDefault()`. My bad :)

Comment: @KeyurPATEL it happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, I did not try on editor.

```
tbl=tbl.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("studentId"))
.Select(new {id = row.Field<int>("studentId"),name = 
 row.Field<int> 
("studentName")}). Distinct ()
.CopyToDataTable();
```